# Focus on second page form with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, index-error

I am trying to fill out [this form](https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/97655130#/basicContact/email) automatically using Selenium. The form consists out of two pages, which both need to be filled. One proceeds to the second page by clicking the orange button stating 'Weiter'.

I have the following code,

```
# load form into chrome, directly via its url
ad_url = 'https://www.immobilienscout24.de/expose/97655130'
form_url_end = '#/basicContact/email'
url = ad_url + form_url_end 
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)

# code which fills out first page correctly

# switch to second page
window_before = browser.window_handles[0]
browser.find_element_by_xpath(
   '//*[@id="is24-de"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/form/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/button',
   ).click()
window_after = browser.window_handles[1]
browser.switch_to.window(window_after)
```

This codes runs fine until the last line –
 `browser.switch_to.window(window_after)`, which yields `IndexError: list index out of range`.

I've followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29982298/7326714).

How do I command selenium to focus on the new page?

---

To fill out the fields in the form, I use e.g for the city field on the first page,

```
city = browser.find_element_by_id("contactForm-city")
city.clear()
city.send_keys('Berlin')
```

Comment: I do not see multiple windows on that page, only dialogs and layers.

Comment: Ah... I thought as the second page has a different url it was a 'new' window. How do I command Selenium to focus on the second page?

Comment: Selenium will "focus" on whatever is currently in the one window.

Comment: If that is correct, then why am I able to fill in the fields on the first page, but using similar code on the second page, I receive a `NoSuchElementException`?

I've added the code I use to fill the fields in the question.

Comment: Ok, just solved it. It needed to wait a bit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740004/7326714

Comment: I do not see any element with `id=contactForm-city` on the second page.